# Default Controller route on MVC project is breaking the default route for the application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a project which has a default page of a classical ASP file (login.asp) So if you type --> www.xxxxxx.com you will land on login page.
Now we have tried to upgrade the project using MVC architecture. The routing on MVC project is as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(name:="DataDownload", url:="download/data-download", defaults:=New With {.controller = "DataDownload", .action = "DownloadXR"})
routes.MapRoute(
   name:="Default",
   url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
)
```

Now the issue is my default url www.xxxxxxx.com has stopped working. Its not setting the default landing page as login.asp.
If I remove the default route from the route config then the download/data-download stops working but the www.xxxxxxx.com starts redirecting the page to login.asp ..I am not sure how to handle the Default controller in MVC project.

---Thanks

Comment: If your project is a mixture of  .net MVC and Classic ASP then I suggest you look at using web.config and the url rewrite module for your custom routing rather than doing it within MVC. See this http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to ignore the default route in the MVC routing, so you should add an `IgnoreRoute` for the home page.

```
' Ignore the default route http://www.xxxxxxx.com/
routes.IgnoreRoute(url:="")

routes.MapRoute(name:="DataDownload", url:="download/data-download", defaults:=New With {.controller = "DataDownload", .action = "DownloadXR"})
routes.MapRoute(
   name:="Default",
   url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
)
```